# How to remove folding in mxCell?

Tags: java, jgraphx

I am using jgraphX, I want to remove folding in particular cell in graph.

There is a method to remove folding from all the cells.(`isCellFoldable`- return `false`)

But I don't want that unique method.

Can I add the folding operation to the popup menu?

Answer (score 0):

There is another method `(isCellFoldable(Object cell, boolean collapse))` that can be used to change the folding property of a single node.

However you'll have to keep somewhere the information of what you've selected as "non foldable".

You can find [here](https://gist.github.com/insac/4076851310ac9abd57cc3b9e65c89904) an example: if you press "a" or "s" on the keyboard the nodes labelled "a" and "s" will toggle the foldable property.